# Cordova: launch SMS app and confirm that an SMS was sent

Tags: cordova

I am looking to Cordova as a possible solution to a problem and want to ask if it is even possible before coding. I can't seem to find any conclusive documentation by Googling.

I want to launch the SMS app and the determine whether the user actually sent the SMS, or just cancelled.

Can I do that with Cordova?

---

[Update] I cannot guarantee that any application is installed on the user's device. I am just serving a web page and want to know if I could launch the SMS app and determine if the user sent an SMS or not with Cordova.

Comment: Android, hopefully iOS too

Comment: Create your own custom plugin that launches the default SMS app. Have you checked [Cordova plugin development](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide). You can even get similar plugins with a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=cordova+sms+plugin&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: Launching the SMS app is one thing, but can check whether an SMS was actually sent, or if he user cancelled?

Comment: Yes you can. You have to set Listeners for outgoing SMSs using the Telephony manager (for Android). I have done a similar plugin to watch for incoming and outgoing calls. However, cordova won't allow you to start a service or a receiver from your Javascript and for that reason you have to do it natively on your activity's code before calling `loadURL()`. That way you will start the receiver and when the listener catches the event you can log it somewhere (databace, file etc.) and read it from your cordova app(when you get back from the SMS app). I guess on iOS can be done the same way

Comment: Actually, I am looking for a pure HTML/JS solution (I  will update the question?). I cannot guarantee that the user will have any app installed, so I am going to serve him a browser page. I can@t have any application event listeners - I can only use Cordova - do you know if it can be done?

Comment: Without going native (i.e. creating or using a plugin) then I am almost sure you cannot do that. The only thing you can do, though, is launch sms app using `<a href="sms:+123456789>send sms</a>`. You have to also define `<access origin="sms:*" launch-external="yes"/>` in your config.xml file. But you will not be able to determine if the user sent the sms or not

Comment: On iOS you should use the sms plugin, it uses the message compose view controller (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/index.html), it's a native component that will be available on iPhones only, there is no app required to be installled. It will tell you if the message was sent. it will show the same screen that is show following @JcDenton86, but that approach doesn't give any feedback. I think android sms plugin uses an intent to any app that can send messages and give a result back from the app that actually sent it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to send sms using cordova.

If you just want to open the SMS app with a clicked number, just add sms:*YOURNUMBER*
 to `a href`.

This is a SMS plugin: https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin

It also has a callback

```
    var success = function () { alert('Message sent successfully'); };
    var error = function (e) { alert('Message Failed:' + e); };
    sms.send(number, message, options, success, error);
```

Hope I could help.

Cheers

Comment: Google has changed their policy on allowing SMS messages to be sent in an app. Your app may not fall under the allowed/exception criteria.  For more details: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303